# Использование конструкторов базового класса

Tags: java

Есть 2 класса: `A`, `B`. Где `B` наследует `A`. В классе `B` конструкторы будут полностью совпадать с конструкторами класса `A`. Можно ли как-то не копируя каждый конструктор с последующим вызовом `super(args...)` отнаследовать их?

Просто ради экономии сил, времени и места.

P.S. в с++ например можно написать `using A::A;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нельзя. super() - единственный выход.